# How do I align two text within two nodes vertically, where one is underlined, or they have different heights (due to the presence of descenders)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the image here and the code below.  How can I get the vertical level of the text in the nodes to align correctly here?  I was using tikz in preference to a \table since I needed to draw lines like below - I figure using a a regular \table would not encounter this problem.

It is not simply a problem of the underline (though that makes it more pronounced), but the y-pos of "email" seems slightly below "phone_number", also.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows.meta,shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\mylw}{1pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small, minimum height=0.8cm, line width=\mylw]
    \draw  (0, 0) 
    node [rectangle, draw] (c0) {\underline{customer\_id}} 
    node [rectangle, draw, right= -\mylw of c0]  (c1) {email}
    node [rectangle, draw, right= -\mylw of c1]  (c2) {phone\_ number};

    \draw        
    node [rectangle, draw, below=of c0] (c2) {\underline{customer\_id}} 
    node [rectangle, draw, black, right= -\mylw  of c2] (c3)       {street};
    node [rectangle, draw, black, right= -\mylw  of c2] (c4)       {suburb};

    \draw[->, rounded corners=5pt] (c2.south) -- ++(0, -0.5) -- ++(-1.5, 0.0) -- ++(0, 1.5) -- ++(1.5, 0.0) -- (c0.south);

    \end{tikzpicture}        
\end{document}
```

Comment: adding a `\strut` at the end of every cell will guarantee uniform baselines.

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer if you wish to respond.  At large magnification, this works even better than the \vphantom{pq1} below, which is still some tiny fractions off alignment with the underscore. (Commenting for posterity for any future reader.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding a `\strut` at the end of each line will ensure uniform baselines.
(`\strut` is defined to have the maximum height and depth of parentheses, which,
at least for the computer modern fonts, are designed to properly enclose all
reasonable baseline notation.)

here's the revised code, with a few additional fixes (one less semicolon in the
second `\draw` block, a change from `[c2` to `[c3]` for the positioning of
"suburb", and the omission of a space after one of the `\_` connectors).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows.meta,shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\mylw}{1pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small, minimum height=0.8cm, line width=\mylw]
    \draw  (0, 0) 
    node [rectangle, draw] (c0) {\underline{customer\_id}\strut} 
    node [rectangle, draw, right= -\mylw of c0]  (c1) {email\strut}
    node [rectangle, draw, right= -\mylw of c1]  (c2) {phone\_number\strut};

    \draw        
    node [rectangle, draw, below=of c0] (c2) {\underline{customer\_id}\strut} 
    node [rectangle, draw, black, right= -\mylw  of c2] (c3)       {street\strut}
    node [rectangle, draw, black, right= -\mylw  of c3] (c4)       {suburb\strut};

    \draw[->, rounded corners=5pt] (c2.south) -- ++(0, -0.5) -- ++(-1.5, 0.0) -- ++(0, 1.5) -- ++(1.5, 0.0) -- (c0.south);

    \end{tikzpicture}        
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 3):

I think the `tikz` way to solve the problem is setting `text height=...` and `text depth=...`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows.meta,shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={rectangle, draw, text height=2.5ex, text depth=1ex},}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\mylw}{1pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small, minimum height=0.8cm, line width=\mylw]
    \draw  (0, 0) 
    node [mynode] (c0) {\underline{customer\_id}} 
    node [mynode, right= -\mylw of c0]  (c1) {email}
    node [mynode, right= -\mylw of c1]  (c2) {phone\_ number};

    \draw        
    node [mynode, below=of c0] (c2) {\underline{customer\_id}} 
    node [mynode, black, right= -\mylw  of c2] (c3)       {street};
    node [mynode, black, right= -\mylw  of c2] (c4)       {suburb};

    \draw[->, rounded corners=5pt] (c2.south) -- ++(0, -0.5) -- ++(-1.5, 0.0) -- ++(0, 1.5) -- ++(1.5, 0.0) -- (c0.south);

    \end{tikzpicture}        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `\vphantom` command in every node with text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows.meta,shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\mylw}{1pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small, minimum height=0.8cm, line width=\mylw]
    \draw  (0, 0) 
    node [rectangle, draw] (c0) {\underline{customer\_id}\vphantom{pq/1}} 
    node [rectangle, draw, right= -\mylw of c0]  (c1) {email\vphantom{pq/1}}
    node [rectangle, draw, right= -\mylw of c1]  (c2) {phone\_ number\vphantom{pq/1}};

    \draw        
    node [rectangle, draw, below=of c0] (c2) {\underline{customer\_id}\vphantom{pq/1}} 
    node [rectangle, draw, black, right= -\mylw  of c2] (c3)       {street\vphantom{pq/1}};
    node [rectangle, draw, black, right= -\mylw  of c2] (c4)       {suburb\vphantom{pq/1}};

    \draw[->, rounded corners=5pt] (c2.south) -- ++(0, -0.5) -- ++(-1.5, 0.0) -- ++(0, 1.5) -- ++(1.5, 0.0) -- (c0.south);

    \end{tikzpicture}        
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want you can make it a command:

```
\newcommand{\fixvalign}{\vphantom{1/pqlHA}}
```

and even more you could include it in `every node` or something